# Is the UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad without a done button issue resolved in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I was looking around and I am not sure whether this problem has been resolved in iOS 5. I found this post

[return or done button in iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767061/uikeyboardtypenumberpad-return-or-done-button-in-ios-5)

which has the bit of code below, but I am not sure where should I put this?

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
} else {
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all add observer for UIKeyboardDidShowNotification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

and in keyboardDidShow: write this code to add Done Button

Comment: Don't forget to REMOVE the observer!!  It should be added in viewWillAppear and removed in viewWillDisappear.  If you try to use load/unload instead you can get some flaky behaviors when other screens are stacked on top.